# How to add text onto a circle using CSS and HTML?

Tags: html, css

[image: Right now this is my timer]

[image: I want the timer to look like the picture below with the word "Stop"]

The above is how my timer currently looks.
I want the word "STOP" to be added to my timer but I don't know how.
Keep in mind that it's actually an input with type text with the text being the time itself. I want to add the word stop on top of the time.
HTML code:

```
<input type="text" name="" value="Start" id="">
```

CSS code:

```
  input[type=text]:focus {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color:  white;
  caret-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  border-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: x-large;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 10px #FF8D3A;
}
```

Comment: hi, perhaps use absolute positioning or move the outer shape out of the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use absolute positioning:

```css
input[type=text]:focus {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  caret-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  border-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: x-large;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 10px #FF8D3A;
}
input[type=text]:focus + .notice{
display:block;
}

.group {
  position: relative;
}

.notice {
  color: #FF8D3A;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  top: 30px;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <input type="text" name="" value="Start" id="">
  <span class="notice">STOP</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @Spentric This works when the entire element is on the top-left hand side but when I center the element so it's in the middle, the stop is left at the top-left hand side of the class.

Comment: @tellmeOberlin You have to make the parent of the input `position:relative`. In my example, I wrapped it in a div with the class `group` which had `position:relative` applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you this solution, by using flex css, as extra, I provided a small JS to get timer.

```js
function refresh() {
    var t = 1000; // rafraîchissement en millisecondes
    setTimeout('showDate()', t);
}

function showDate() {
    var date = new Date();
    var h = date.getHours();
    var m = date.getMinutes();
    var s = date.getSeconds();
    if (h < 10) {
        h = '0' + h;
    }
    if (m < 10) {
        m = '0' + m;
    }
    if (s < 10) {
        s = '0' + s;
    }
    document.getElementById('horloge').value = h + ':' + m + ':' + s;
    refresh();
}
```

```css
.circle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: x-large;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 10px #FF8D3A;
}
.circle div {
  align-self: center;
}
.circle b {
  color: #FF8D3A;
}
.circle input {
  width:70%;
  border:none;
  text-align:center;
  font-size: x-large;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<body onload="showDate()">
  <div class="circle">
    <div>
       <b>STOP</b>
       <input type="text" value="00:39:43" id="horloge" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```